# how to check for ldpi hdpi images in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I had a scenario where I have 2 images with same name but of different sizes in hdpi,mdpi folders like below:

```
drawable-hdpi/a.png 
drawable-mdpi/a.png
```

I tried to access the images in my code as below:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
int drawableID = this.getResources().getIdentifier("a", "drawable", getPackageName());
iv.setImageResource(drawableID);
```

So, is there a way in which I can change settings in emulator so that I can create 2 different emulators so that it takes images from different folders, because as of now I am able to see only image from mdpi folder.

Can any one help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Of course. Multiple emulators are reqired, to make this kind of tests. Make an emulator with an hdpi screen (normalized density: 240 dpi).

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.genymotion.com/
It's faster than common emulator, and you can easy create devices with different dpi.